# How to use multiple sftp outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm new in Spring Integration and I'm working with two process:

1.- Read files from sftp, save information. I use method "mget".

2.- After of save information, rename files processed in sftp server with method "mput".

this is my configuration:

```
<bean id="filePrinter" class="com.maven.integration.FilePrinter" />

<int:channel id="outboundChannel"></int:channel>

<int:channel id="aggregateResultsChannel"/>

<int:channel id="toGet"></int:channel>

<int:gateway id="simpleGateway" service-interface="com.maven.integration.FileGateway"
    default-request-channel="ftpChannel" />

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway 
    session-factory="sftpClientFactory"
    request-channel="ftpChannel" 
    command="mget" 
    command-options="-R -P"
    expression="payload" 
    filename-regex="(new|.*.csv)"
    mode="IGNORE"
    local-directory-expression="@targetDir.get() + #remoteDirectory"
    reply-channel="outboundChannel"
    >
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-gateway>

<int:splitter input-channel="outboundChannel" output-channel="toGet"/>

<bean id="targetDir" class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference">
    <constructor-arg value="${target}"/>
</bean>

<int:service-activator ref="filePrinter" method="print"
    input-channel="toGet"/>


    <int-sftp:outbound-gateway 
    session-factory="sftpClientFactory"
    request-channel="toGet" 
    command="mput" 
    command-options="-R"
    local-directory="src/test/"
    expression="payload" 
    filename-regex="(new|.*.csv)"
    mode="IGNORE"
    remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName() + '.ack'"
    remote-directory-expression="#remoteDirectory"
    reply-channel="aggregateResultsChannel"
    >
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-gateway>

<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregateResultsChannel"/>
```

currently only the first outbound-gateway with mget command is executed, but the second outbound-gateway is not executed, how could the second process run?

Answer (score 0):

Because your `toGet` is a simple `DirectChannel` with the "only one per message subscriber" logic. At the same time your `mput` gateway uses that as its `request-channel="toGet"` sharing this channel with the 
`<int:service-activator>`. And since this `is earlier in the config, it is a first subscriber in the`toGet`and therefore only this one process the message sent to the`toGet` by the splitter.

I think what you need to do (if the story is still about `mput`) is exactly opposite with what you have in `mget`. So, you should do that logic alongside with the splitting, not after. Therefore you should send `MGET` result to the splitter and to the `MPUT` in parallel. For this purpose I suggest you to change your `outboundChannel` to the `<publish-subscribe-channel>` and use this `outboundChannel` in the `mput` gateway for its `request-channel`.